# How can I write code to access a text file when my class and the text file are in an Executable JAR?

Tags: java, deployment, executable-jar

I know this question has been asked many, many times before, but the answers don't seem to help me. Here is  my specific issue:

I have a class "TaQL" that accesses two text files from within its void main(String args[]) method. The two text files are in the same package as this class: package "taql". The following code runs fine within Eclipse (Mars) IDE:

```
    String stoplist = TaQL.class.getResource(stoplist).toURI().getPath();
    String input = TaQL.class.getResource(input).toURI().getPath();
```

When I output these two strings I get the correct path to the resource and the code hums along.

However, when I use this method after packaging everything up in a JAR, both strings return "null".

Here is what my code does with each of these text files in the non-JAR version

1. Get filename string for each text file.
2. create a new File object from one string and a new FileReader object from the other.
3. These are fed into a stoplist function and a data input iterator, respectively.

What I really need to be able to do is to seamlessly access these two text files once they are all in a JAR and then use some reference to these to create a File and FileReader object.

Here is some diagnostic code I put in my main method. It will show what the JAR file is seeing as far as files (note that both input and stoplist are filename strings):

```
    System.out.println("intput argument" + input);

    System.out.println("Resource path"+TaQL.class.getResource(stoplist));

    stoplist = TaQL.class.getResource(stoplist).toURI().getPath();
    input = TaQL.class.getResource(input).toURI().getPath();

    System.out.println("Path"+stoplist);
    System.out.println("Input path" + input);
```

command line output from running the JAR version of my program (note that this code works perfectly fine when I run from Eclipse)

[image]

Comment: It is incorrect to think of it as a text file within a jar, a jar is itself a file, so the "text file" is simply a portion of the JAR archive file.

Comment: @JamesWierzba thanks James...that was my confusion! Going to stream inputs has solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually access the bytes of those files that may be in a jar file you need to use Class#getResourceAsStream(stopList). The URI will give you a path that cannot be used with File or FileInputStream. It's working in your IDE because the IDE has not yet packaged up the files, therefore the #getPath finds an actual file path.

So try this instead:

```
try (Reader inputReader = 
        new InputStreamReader(
            TaQL.class.getResourceAsStream(input))) {

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputReader);

    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null;) {
        // do something with the line
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, so once its in a JAR you have to work with streams, not files, correct?

Comment: Correct. This will safely access it no matter how it is packaged.

Comment: Yep, this worked. Is there a way to read the whole file in at once, or only line by line?

Comment: Okay @Bey, a little out of scope from your question but I updated my answer to include how to read the file line by line.

Comment: thanks..I know a bit "greedy" of me...that's why I accepted your answer first. I hate it when people string others along with "...oh and..." questions. Much appreciated!